# Where in an installed TeXLive texmf tree is mathtrip?

Tags: texmf, tds

Where in an installed TeXLive 2022 `texmf` tree does one find the `mathtrip` package?

I was unsuccessful in locating it through either a (macOS) search nor `texdoc mathtrip`. When I open the pdf from The CTAN page  https://ctan.org/pkg/mathtrip, it shows the source as `\info`mathtrip`.

Comment: its licence is not compatible so it is not in texlive, but you can install it from ctan

Answer (score 1):

Its licence is not compatible so it is not in texlive, but you can install it from ctan.